# Connecting Lambda in a VPC to SQS

Tags: java, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I currently have a Lambda function. I want to run it under a VPC. I followed the instructions from this github repo to get started with - https://gist.github.com/reggi/dc5f2620b7b4f515e68e46255ac042a7

Here are the following steps I followed:

1. Created a new vpc for testing purposes.
2. Created 2 new subnets under the VPC - one to connect to the NAT and one to connect the IGW.
3. Created an internet gateway and a NAT since the routing tables need to be attached to them.
4. I created two new route tables as well - one pointing to the NAT with destination address 0.0.0.0/0 and one pointing to the Internet Gateway with destination address 0.0.0.0/0.
5. Manually associated the two routing tables to the respective subnets.
6. Created a default security group and assigned it to the VPC - I did not change any incoming or outgoing rules.
7. Assigned the vpc created in the above step, the two subnets created in the above step and the security group to the lambda function I have.

I keep getting the exception that the AmazonSDK timeout out connecting to SQS:

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443 [sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/54.239.28.81] failed: connect timed out
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1113)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1063)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:743)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.doInvoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:1740)
at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:1716)
at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.executeReceiveMessage(AmazonSQSClient.java:1380)
at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.receiveMessage(AmazonSQSClient.java:1356)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you make sure your Lambda function is only running in the subnet with the NAT gateway?

Comment: I added both the subnets - one connected to the NAT routing table and the one connected to the IGW to the lambda function, should I be choosing the subnet only with the NAT gateway?

Comment: Why would you think 2 subnets with totally different configurations would work the same? The private subnet (the one with the NAT gateway) is the only one that will allow both VPC access and SQS access to the Lambda function.

Comment: @MarkB: I was merely only following the instructions provided in the link. I wasn't aware the private subnet is the one that would allow both VPC access and SQS access. Thank you for the suggestion again. I'll double check the way I am setting up the subnets and try it once again

Comment: In the link you posted, under "Set your lambda up" it specifically adds the Lambda function only to the private subnets with NAT gateway attached.